# Random forest minimum number of observations

Tags: machine-learning, regression, random-forest

I have around 5000-6000 observations of nearly 8-10 variables (of which 2 are discrete, categorical) and a single numerical target parameter. As per initial evaluation, random forest regression might be a good algorithm for the current case.

Is the current observations/variables count adequate for the proposed method? If other regression algorithms are recommended as things are described currently, kindly let me know.

Comment: RF works perfectly well even with the iris data, with only 150 samples in total for 3 classes (and actually less used for training, after train-test split or cross-validation).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The important is not the number of observation but the quality of this observations. If you have a look at toy datasets of sklearn they are way smaller than that.

Random forest is a good algorithm when there is small data since it is a bagging of decision trees with bootstrap. Each decision tree is feed with a sample of data with replacement, in this way even if the data is small there are bigger chances of making a good model.

In a high level, yes it seems a good way to go, but with out knowing more at the data is hard to tell.

I would suggest to give it a try with a Generalized Linear Model, a support vector machine and a gradient boosting.  Since your data is small you will not need much computation time for it.